# fetching savedInstanceState values, nullpointerexception

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    savedInstanceState.putString("foo", "bar");
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("foo");

  Log.i("debug", "saved data: " + myString);
}
```

Im trying to preserve some values in an activity, but i recieve the following error: `06-23 23:09:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(17584): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{se.johanberntsson.activitytest/se.johanberntsson.activitytest.TestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

What did I miss here? Thanks

Comment: Well testing if `savedInstanceState` to see if it's `null` before calling `getString(...)` would be a good start. How are you trying to "preserve some values"? Perhaps using `SharedPreferences` might be a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `onSaveInstanceState` for saving values in savedInstanceState Bundle as:

```
public String strfoo="";
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main2);
            //comment this line you only fatch values from savedInstanceState
            String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("foo");
            Log.i("debug", "saved data: " + myString);
            // savedInstanceState.putString("foo", "bar");
            strfoo="bar"; set value here
        }

        @Override
        public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
          String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("foo");
          Log.i("debug", "saved data: " + myString);
        }

      @Override

      public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         savedInstanceState.putString("foo", strfoo);
         super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

       }
```

Comment: Thank you! But when i start my new activity -> press "back" -> start the same activity again, i dont see "bar" in my log. Shouldnt `onRestoreInstanceState` be called at that time?

Comment: onRestoreInstanceState called only when any config. changes occur.

Comment: but i think when u press back button both onRestoreInstanceState and onSaveInstanceState not called. so change your logic and use sharedpreferce to store value when user press back button by override onKeyDown or onBackPressed

Comment: and when user press back key onuserleavehint method also called so try to save value on onuserleavehint

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I get "onRestoreInstanceState must override or implement a supertype method" when trying to do this inside a Fragment class.